# SQL server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am getting following error in all my websites when i am trying to access the database from websites.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Actually i have changed my server IP address.

Comment: Was this working before and just now stopped or is this a new database server for your websites?

Answer (score 1):

If your web applications are calling the SQL server via IP, it is because you changed the IP and will need to change this in your application.

If your web applications are using DNS, it is probably because the DNS entries for the server have not been updated properly, or the old for the old IP address is still there, you could check this by running WireShark on the application server and seeing where the request is going.

1. Make sure your domain controllers have no record of the old machine name in your forward lookup zones.
2. Make sure there is not an entry in the DHCP table.
3. Make sure the DNS entry is not locally cached, you can check if it is on a windows machine by opening command prompt and typing ipconfig /displaydns and clear it out of the list using ipconfig /flushdns. If it stays in your dns list, make sure you do not have a host file entry for this server.